# Why is there a warning when an unused non-string variable is initialized locally?

Tags: c++, warnings, local-variables

Why does Xcode show an "unused variable" warning when I initialize a non-string variable locally, but not when I do so globally?

```
int bruh = 21;

int main()
{
    int bro = 10;
}
```

For example, in this case, the local variable `int bro` would show the warning because I don't use it anywhere in main(). Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: You can use `bruh` from a different translation unit. Xcode can't know if it's really unused.

Comment: `bruh` has external linkage and may be referred to by other translation units.

Comment: To illustrate: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/61vnfa

Comment: Extension to chris's answer above: note the use of the `static` keyword. In this context it is forcing internal linkage. Here's some reading on the various different types of linkages, durations, and other groovy things: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: @ThomasSablik Why does `bro` being unused get a warning? Is it really that big of an issue for Xcode to complain about it?

Comment: @Anthony what it's doing is telling you you've got a variable you aren't using. All too often that's a bug. For example, `int x,y;` and later in the code you have a typo and use `x` where you should have used `y`. The compiler can't warn you about the typo (at least not until until we get psychic compilers), but it can point out that `y` was never used.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, so it's mostly there just to remind the programmer of potential logic errors?

Comment: Yep. That's what warnings are in general. The source code is syntactically correct and can be transformed into executable code, but the executable code might not do what you wanted. Very important in my book. Any time the compiler can tell you that you have a bug, that's potentially less debugging you'll have to do later.

Comment: Mind you, watch out for nanny compilers. Sometimes people get a little too anal and wind up burying the real problems in a flood of trivialities.

Comment: @user4581301 gotcha :)